# How to Parallel Prims Algorithm in Graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph-algorithm, spark-graphx, prims-algorithm

So I'm trying to write a parallel algorithm for Prims Algorithm but I cant quite figure out how to do it using Spark Graphx. I've looked pretty hard for resources but there aren't a lot of examples of implementing shortest path algorithms in graphx. I think I need to use divide and conquer and split the graph into sub graphs and then merge their MSTs.

Graphx Resource:
http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html#the-property-graph

Parallel Prims Resource:
https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/5DV050/VT10/handouts/F10.pdf

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util._

object ParallelPrims {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Parallel Prims").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logFile = "NodeData.txt"

    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    // Splitting off header node
    val headerAndRows = logData.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
    val header = headerAndRows.first
    val data = headerAndRows.filter(_(0) != header(0))
    // Parse number of Nodes and Edges from header
    val numNodes = header(0).toInt
    val numEdges = header(1).toInt

    val vertexArray = new Array[(Long, String)](numNodes)

    val edgeArray = new Array[Edge[Int]](numEdges)
    // Create vertex array
    var count = 0
    for (count <- 0 to numNodes - 1) {
      vertexArray(count) = (count.toLong + 1, ("v" + (count + 1)).toString())
    }
    count = 0
    val rrdarr = data.take(data.count.toInt)
    // Create edge array
    for (count <- 0 to (numEdges - 1)) {
      val line = rrdarr(count)
      val cols = line.toList
      val edge = Edge(cols(0).toLong, cols(1).toLong, cols(2).toInt)
      edgeArray(count) = Edge(cols(0).toLong, cols(1).toLong, cols(2).toInt)
    }
    // Creating graphx graph
    val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
    val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)

    val graph: Graph[String, Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)

    graph.triplets.take(6).foreach(println)

  }

}
```

NodeData.txt

```
4,6
1,2,5
1,3,8
1,4,4
2,3,8
2,4,7
3,4,1
```

Output

```
((1,v1),(2,v2),5)
((1,v1),(3,v3),8)
((1,v1),(4,v4),4)
((2,v2),(3,v3),8)
((2,v2),(4,v4),7)
((3,v3),(4,v4),1)
```

Comment: Your assignment handout describes the parallel algorithm. What have you tried to implement that, and where are you stuck? SO is not  somewhere you should ask people to write your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the implementation part is where I'm stuck. I think I need to use some sort of Neighborhood Aggregation but the graphx examples I find don't explain how that can be used to find the shortest path. 
[link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/graphx-programming-guide.html#map-reduce-triplets-mapreducetriplets)

Comment: I don't think you're going to get many answers until you show us what you have tried. *Of course* the implementation part is where you are stuck, that's what the assignment's all about, and people here aren't very keen to just answer your assignment for you. And (in my view) I can't see how it helps you to get someone else to write it.

Comment: Actually it isn't specifically an assignment, I'm going above and beyond the requirements for a project for my algorithms class(I thought this might be fun...)
Here is the code in it's current form, sorry it's not optimized the best. This is my first time using Spark. I think the next step is figuring out how to create an MST in parallel.
https://gist.github.com/gigglesbw4/a280b379d0d329467dd45c80c9993240

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the code there?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul updated the code, I think the default for graphx is a directed graph so I may need to go through the nodes again and add the reverse since it should be undirected

Comment: You can always just reverse the direction of the graph with `Graph.reverse` -- no need to build edges in both directions. Unless, of course, the weights are different in either direction. But what logic have you tried? Basically your code got us the test data. And we're not going to go read your homework assignment -- include the basic logic of what you are trying to accomplish ("Given this graph .... I need to find .... and the results should look like ...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my version of Prims algorithm.

```
var graph : Graph [String, Int] = ...

// just empty RDD for MST
var MST = sc.parallelize(Array[EdgeTriplet[Int, Int]]())

// pick random vertex from graph
var Vt: RDD[VertexId] = sc.parallelize(Array(graph.pickRandomVertex))

// do until all vertices is in Vt set 
val vcount = graph.vertices.count
while (Vt.count < vcount) {

  // rdd to make inner joins
  val hVt = Vt.map(x => (x, x)) 

  // add key to make inner join
  val bySrc = graph.triplets.map(triplet => (triplet.srcId, triplet))

  // add key to make inner join
  val byDst = graph.triplets.map(triplet => (triplet.dstId, triplet)) 

  // all triplet where source vertex is in Vt
  val bySrcJoined = bySrc.join(hVt).map(_._2._1) 

  // all triplet where destinaiton vertex is in Vt
  val byDstJoined = byDst.join(hVt).map(_._2._1)

  // sum previous two rdds and substract all triplets where both source and destination vertex in Vt
  val candidates = bySrcJoined.union(byDstJoined).subtract(byDstJoined.intersection(bySrcJoined))

  // find triplet with least weight
  val triplet = candidates.sortBy(triplet => triplet.attr).first

  // add triplet to MST 
  MST = MST.union(sc.parallelize(Array(triplet)))

  // find out whether we should add source or destinaiton vertex to Vt
  if (!Vt.filter(x => x == triplet.srcId).isEmpty) {
    Vt = Vt.union(sc.parallelize(Array(triplet.dstId)))
  } else {
    Vt = Vt.union(sc.parallelize(Array(triplet.srcId)))
  }
}

// final minimum spanning tree
MST.collect.foreach(p => println(p.srcId + " " + p.attr + " " + p.dstId))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code runs in parallel and gives me a minimum spanning. How fast does it run on your cluster? I am having an issues getting it to work on data sets with more than 30 nodes. Even after increasing the memory allocation for the job I am still getting 
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Here is what I currently have, Ill update the code in my question after I figure out what is causing the memory issues.
https://gist.github.com/gigglesbw4/f25fbec2b6873015d6bebec0014431b1

Comment: for me your example with 50 vertices works ... but it goes pretty long

Comment: Using a simple counter rather than calling `Vt.count` action every time through the loop, could remove one of the possible bottlenecks.